# How to get custom SOAP header from WCF service response in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, wcf, header

I'm trying to get custom response message header in Silverlight application.

on server-side new MessageHeader added to response headers:

```
OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(MessageHeader.CreateHeader("headerName", "headerNS", "The header value"));
```

and I can see this header in Fiddler:

> s:Envelope [
>   xmlns:s=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/
>   ]
>
> s:Header
>
> headerName [ xmlns=headerNS ] The
>   header value

But, I can't find a way to read header value in Silverlight application service callback:

```
            using (new OperationContextScope(proxy.InnerChannel))
            {
                var headers = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders;
                // headers is null :(

            }
```

Does anyone encountered with similar issue?

Answer (score 1):

Getting SOAP headers in responses on Silverlight isn't as easy as it should be. If you use the event-based callbacks, you're out of luck - it just doesn't work. You need to use the Begin/End-style operation call, like in the example below.

```
void Button_Click(...)
{
   MyClient client = new MyClient();
   IClient proxy = (IClient)client; // need to cast to the [ServiceContract] interface
   proxy.BeginOperation("hello", delegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   {
      using (new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
      {
         proxy.EndOperation(asyncResult);
         var headers = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders;
         // now you can access it.
      }
   });
}
```

Notice that you cannot use the generated client (from slsvcutil / add service reference) directly, you need to cast it to the interface, since the Begin/End methods are not exposed (explicitly implemented) on the client class.

Answer (score 0):

To get headers from http request try to use [Client HTTP stack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd920295%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

The easies way to do it is to register the prefix, for example:

```
WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("http://", WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but question is about SOAP message headers

Comment: Yes, I understand, but I have a feeling that still this has to do with Http client stack in SL. I will try to investigate this - maybe I will find way to help you.