# SlSvcUtil ignores MessageHeader properties

Tags: wcf, silverlight, slsvcutil

To show my problem I created a simple WCF service with operations that use a message class with `[MessageContract]` attribute. This message contains the `MyHeader` property and is annotated with the `[MessageHeader]` attribute.

```cs
[MessageContract] public class HeaderedMessage
{
    [MessageHeader] public string MyHeader { get; set; }
}

[ServiceContract] public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract] void GetDataUsingDataContract(HeaderedMessage headered);
}

public class Service : IService
{
    public void GetDataUsingDataContract(HeaderedMessage headered) { }
}
```

Then I tried to generate the proxy classes for Silverlight 4 (or 5) using `SlSvcUtil.exe`:

```
slsvcutil.exe http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/MessageHeaderedService/?wsdl
```

Without any warning the message headers are totally ignored in the generated classes. Hence the `HeaderedMessage` **does not contain any** property at all.

```cs
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="HeaderedMessage", WrapperNamespace="http://tempuri.org/", IsWrapped=true)]
public partial class HeaderedMessage
{
    public HeaderedMessage()
    {
    }
}
```

I did not find any information at MSDN or through Google search about this weired behaviour. Has anybody else issues with this?

I also tried to use [Portable Class Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx) extension to use the `IService` contract directly through `ChannelFactory` within the Silverlight application. As the `System.ServiceModel` assemblies of Silverlight don't contain the `MessageHeaderAttribute` class it cannot be compiled.

**Update**: Missing generated WSDL and the WCF `System.ServiceModel` section:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" name="Service" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
      <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/MessageHeaderedService/?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://tempuri.org/"/>
      <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/MessageHeaderedService/?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/>
    </xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="HeaderedMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:HeaderedMessage"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="HeaderedMessage_Headers">
    <wsdl:part name="MyHeader" element="tns:MyHeader"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="IService_GetDataUsingDataContract_OutputMessage"/>
  <wsdl:portType name="IService">
    <wsdl:operation name="GetDataUsingDataContract">
      <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService/GetDataUsingDataContract" name="HeaderedMessage" message="tns:HeaderedMessage"/>
      <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService/GetDataUsingDataContractResponse" message="tns:IService_GetDataUsingDataContract_OutputMessage"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" type="tns:IService">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetDataUsingDataContract">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IService/GetDataUsingDataContract" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input name="HeaderedMessage">
        <soap:header message="tns:HeaderedMessage_Headers" part="MyHeader" use="literal"/>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="Service">
    <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_IService">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/MessageHeaderedService/"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

The WCF config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="MessageHeaderedService.Service">
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/MessageHeaderedService/" />
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
      <endpoint address ="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MessageHeaderedService.IService">
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Somehow related question [found here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406007/how-to-get-custom-http-header-from-wcf-service-response-in-silverlight). But it's related to **custom** headers and not `[MessageHeader]` attribute.